# É correto misturar formato JSON com MySQL?

Tags: mysql, json, laravel

Estou ajudando a desenvolver uma aplicação web em Laravel para uma empresa. Ela possui diversos Modals incluso nelas (inclusive modal que leva para outro modal).

Para chamar esses modals, eu estou utilizando JQuery, como o exemplo adiante:

```
$('.classe-do-modal').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let modal = $('#idDoModal');   

    modal.modal({show : true});    
});
```

No meu controller, estou retornando os valores no formato JSON dentro da minha função *show*.

```
public function show($id){
    $variavelModel = Model::where('outro_model_id',$id)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
    return response()->json($variavelModel);
}
```

Em outro arquivo de JavaScript, tem adicionalmente os seguintes comandos:

```
      let p = JSON.parse($(this).attr('data-entity'));

      if(p.id) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'url/daRota/'+p.id,
                type: "GET",
                data : {"_token":"{{ csrf_token() }}"},
                dataType: "json",
                success:function(data) {
                  if(data){ 
                    $('#id-da-div').empty();     
                    $.each(data, function(key, value){
                      $('#id-da-div').append(value);
                    });

                  }
                }
              });
            }
```

E para cadastrar os dados, possuo como o exemplo abaixo:

```
 public function store(Request $request){
        MeuModel::create(array_merge($request->all(, ['outro_model_id'=>$request->outro_model_id]));

        $variavel_model = MeuModel::where('outro_model_id',$request->outro_model_id)->get()->count();        

        OutroModel::where('id', $request->outro_model_id)->update('outro_model', $variavel_model);

        alert()->success('Sucesso', 'cadastrada com sucesso!');
        return back();

    }
```

Acima apenas há um exemplo de como estou cadastrando os dados que desejo. Estou utilizando o banco de dados.

Porém a principal pergunta é o seguinte. É correto utilizar o banco de dados para cadastrar e depois retirar os dados do banco de dados e transformá-los para JSON? Como exemplo utilizando uma requisição do AJAX para obter o uso da minha rota no Laravel? A principio, não estou conseguindo puxar direto do banco os dados sem a requisição do AJAX. Acredito que isso seja por causa dos *modals*. É correto usar essa forma de pegar os dados misturando o JSON com MySQL?

Comment: E que problema você está pensando que poderia ter? Por que você acha que uma coisa tem relação com outra?

Comment: Não tenho certeza se esse método seria uma "gambiarra" ou um método eficiente para resolver o problema.

Comment: *É correto utilizar o banco de dados para cadastrar e depois retirar os dados do banco de dados e transformá-los para JSON?*, não sei se entendi bem sua dúvida mas o banco salva os dados no seu formato próprio que não importa para o código (mesmo q o banco possa salvar em json), porque ele te retorna os dados e vc deve transformá-los no que for preciso para apresentar, seja json, seja texto, csv, uma table ou qualquer outra coisa, por isso não vejo nenhum problema ai. Agora isso e o Ajax são coisas completamente diferentes na sua pergunta

Comment: Obrigado @RicardoPontual, esclareceu bem a minha dúvida. Já em questão ao Ajax, eu estou ainda confuso com a sua funcionalidade. Sei que tem sentido em questões como requisições. Porém ainda em minha cabeça estou assimilando muito ao formato JSON pois é o que mais vejo referente a uma explicação dessa funcionalidade. Em tutoriais online por exemplo vejo alguns cursinhos utilizando o JSON como exemplo de explicar o AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No caso apresentado acima você está utilizando uma base de dados MySQL, ou seja, este é o local onde você está persistindo os dados da sua aplicação.

Já o JSON, é uma estrutura de dados que você está utilizando para comunicar o front-end com back-end, neste caso não tem bem certo ou errado, na verdade o erro está em como você interpreta "misturando JSON com MySQL".

Você não está misturando JSON com MySQL, você está utilizando uma base de dados MySQL para persistir os dados e JSON para definir uma estrutura de dados de comunicação entre front-end e back-end.

O Laravel possui algumas coleções, métodos e helpers para simplificar algumas tarefas, tais como pegar um valor que vem do banco e formatar ele para a estrutura de dados JSON. Exemplo: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/responses#json-responses

Você está indo no caminho certo...

Comment: A sua resposta está completa?

Comment: Complementei agora. Me desculpe, por engano acabei publicando de forma incompleta.

Comment: Me parece que errei em questão do título mesmo. Pois estou com bastante duvidas referente ao JSON. Pois pra mim parece uma maneira confusa transformar os dados em JSON ainda. Mas a tua resposta ja tirou a minha duvida.

Comment: Perfeito, como você disse, é resposta. Não tome o que direi a seguir como única solução e prática única adotada universalmente, mas a considere: normalmente utilizamos a estrutura JSON para construir API ou lidar com comunicação assíncrona, é um formato aberto, mais elegante do que XML, facilmente manipulável e visualmente agradável. É muito comum você ver soluções prontas que transmitem dados em JSON, principalmente entre o back-end e front-end, isso te dá flexibilidade, você pode "plugar" um front-end a sua aplicação, basta que ele lidar com JSON e com a estrutura que você criou...

Answer (score 1):

Tudo certo!
O MySQL suporta o formato JSON!
Lembre-se de usá-lo no formato da coluna na tabela!
Na migration do laravel é possível usar o comando

```
$table->json('modal_content');
```

Isso cria a coluna do tipo JSON!

Na view, você pode usar o Blade Template para converter os dados JSON do modal diretamente na variável que vai preencher  o modal.. ou seja:

Em vez de:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: 'url/daRota/'+p.id,
            type: "GET",
            data : {"_token":"{{ csrf_token() }}"},
            dataType: "json",
            success:function(data) {
              if(data){ 
                $('#id-da-div').empty();     
                $.each(data, function(key, value){
                  $('#id-da-div').append(value);
                });

              }
            }
          });
        }
```

Use:

```
$('#id-da-div').append({{ $modal_value }}); // sendo $modal_value uma variável PHP obtida pelo controller e enviada para a view !
```

Boa sorte!